# Better word and abbreviation for single month instead of year-to-date

Tags: single-word-requests

In a report I would like to switch between a view which shows year-to-date figures, for example January 100, February 210, March 330 and a view which shows single month figures, in this example January 100, February 11o, March 120.

I am curious wether there is a common expression for single month and an abbreviation for it, like YTD is common for year-to-date.

Comment: [AcronymFinder](https://www.acronymfinder.com/MTD.html) includes MTD, and M = monthly.

Comment: Are you wanting to display the figures for each completed month which contributes to the YTD figure (offering the choice of month after you have clicked on the button) or are you wanting to display the month-to-date figure for the current month only?

Comment: year-to-date figures are not written as January 100. There is usually an actual sentence;

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with *monthly*:

> 2 a : of or relating to a month
>   b : payable or reckoned by the month

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monthly))</sub>

"Monthly sales" is a frequently used expression in business.

'Monthly' does not have an acronym; if you need a short word on a button next to 'YTD', just use 'Month'. Everybody will understand that. If you need it as an axis label, you can even omit it entirely as long as the month names themselves are visible; by default, people will assume the values pertain to the month named directly below.